# How to install PYPI package (Facebook-business, Google-cloud-secret-manager) in Google Cloud Composer

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, pypi, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to install Facebook-business, Google-cloud-secret-manager Pypi package in Google Cloud Manager but after 20 min I am getting below error:

[image]

[image]

Please find the image version as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building my test Composer environment with runtime based on `composer-1.9.1-airflow-1.10.6` image I've faced with probably the same issue missing [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) dependencies that belong to `google-cloud-secret-manager` and `facebook_business` packages, as well as affecting the system core to properly compile image changes.

Fortunately, adding the following packages chain to my `requirements.txt` files permanently fixed the issue:

```
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
google-api-core==1.22.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.4.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.17.1
google-auth==1.20.1
setuptools==49.6.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.27.2
google-cloud-logging==1.15.1
google-cloud-core==1.4.1
protobuf==3.13.0
google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
google-resumable-media==0.7.1
facebook-business==8.0.1
six==1.15.0
mock
pycountry
curlify
requests
```

Composer `gcloud` update command reference guide you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/update).

*FYI.*
You can catch Composer builder logs via GCP [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) and keep track of the runtime image creation progress.

Comment: I really appreciate your instant answer to my question.it worked and  saved a lot of time for me .Thank you very much Keeping helping others good luck!

Comment: And I am curious how did you find the exact list of dependencies would be great if there is any document to know the list of dependencies for a particular python PYPI packages

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help. As I mentioned, the particular dependencies discrepancy might be reflected during image recompiling in [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/).